# How to use different version of Django in virtualenv

Tags: django, virtualenv

I'm trying to run Openblock within a virtualenv, but the problem is Openblock requires Django 1.2.5 and I've already got Django 1.1.1 on the server.

`$ python -c "import django;print django.get_version()"` returns 1.1.1

After activating the virtualenv, the same command returns 1.2.5. So far so good.

But when I run `yolk -l` within the virtualenv it shows 1.1.1 as active and 1.2.5 as non-active.

Comment: Why does it matter what yolk reports? Your test imported the right version, so everything is fine.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742980/virtualenv-yolk-problem

Comment: ...though conveniently enough, the explanations in each set of answers are pretty much complementary.  Hopefully people will get the idea :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install yolk into the virtualenv otherwise it'll list system packages instead; yolk doesn't know anything about the current virtualenv.  So run `pip install yolk` with the virtualenv activated.  (If you've created your virtualenv without `--no-site-packages`, you'll need to run `pip install --upgrade yolk`).

I just recreated this scenario (except with Debian squeeze where the OS version of Django is 1.2.3) and it worked.  With `--no-site-packages`:

```
% . foo/bin/activate
(foo)% yolk -l Django
Django          - 1.2.5        - active 
(foo)% deactivate
```

and without:

```
% . bar/bin/activate
(bar)% yolk -l Django
Django          - 1.2.3        - non-active development (/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6)
Django          - 1.2.5        - active
```

In general, if you run any Python programs installed outside the virtualenv, you shouldn't expect them to know anything about the virtualenv unless they've been written to be aware of virtualenv (e.g. pip's `PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV`).

Comment: I've done that, Nicholas. Is it possible yolk is showing both versions of Django -- the system package 1.1.1 and the virtualenv package 1.2.5.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the virtualenv version of yolk?  Try `which yolk` and make sure it's what you expect.  To be absolutely sure, you could recreate your virtualenv with `--no-site-packages` so there's no possibility the system version of Django gets used.

Comment: You're right. That returns '/usr/local/bin/yolk'. I'm assuming I can't install yolk in the virtualenv because it's already got the site package.

Comment: You can, you just need to use `pip install --upgrade`.  However, I think you'd stay a lot saner if you recreated your virtualenv with `--no-site-packages` so it was more thoroughly isolated from the system.

Answer (score -1):

Virtualenv updates sys.path

run this in and out of the virtualenv to debug.

```
python -c "import sys; print '\n'.join(sys.path)"
python -c "import os; print os.getenv('PYTHONPATH')
```

Try creating the virtualenv with --no-site-packages and see if it still conflicts.

Comment: When I run 'pip install yolk' while the virtualenv is active, I get: 'Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): yolk in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yolk-0.4.1-py2.6.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in /usr/local/pythonenv/openblock/lib/python2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.6.egg (from yolk)'

Comment: I'm confused. I created a new virtual environment with --no-site-packages, activated the virtual environment and ran yolk without even installing it. And it showed dozens of packages installed in the virtualenv despite using the option --no-site-packages.

Comment: That's right - you're still running the system version of yolk.  You need to install yolk into the virtualenv - see my answer, again...

Comment: Virtualenv does nothing with PYTHONPATH.