# Python modules not found in virtualenv

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I can't get modules to run in my virtual environment. Using pandas as an example:

With the virtual env on I run `yolk -l` and get back (shortened version):

```
(basicpython)xxxx@LinuxBox:~/pythonprojects/basicpython$ yolk -l
Python          - 2.7.3        - active development (/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload)
numpy           - 1.6.1        - active 
pandas          - 0.7.0        - active development (/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7)
```

So it is there. But when I try to activate the module I get an error:

```
(basicpython)xxxxx@LinuxBox:~/pythonprojects/basicpython$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

When I turn off the virtual environment and do the same thing it works:

```
(basicpython)xxxxx@LinuxBox:~/pythonprojects/basicpython$ deactivate
xxxx@LinuxBox:~/pythonprojects/basicpython$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd
<module 'pandas' from '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/__init__.pyc'>
```

Any idea why this might be happening (did I miss an install step with virtualenv?)

EDIT: I installed pandas and other libraries while in the virtual environment, does this not install them in the environment?

EDIT 2: I tried reinstalling the packages while in the virtual environment and the system says they are already there:

```
(basicpython)xxxx@LinuxBox:~/pythonprojects/basicpython$ sudo apt-get install               
python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas       python-sympy python-nose
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  python-nose is already the newest version.
  python-numpy is already the newest version.
  ipython is already the newest version.
  ipython-notebook is already the newest version.
  python-matplotlib is already the newest version.
  python-pandas is already the newest version.
  python-scipy is already the newest version.
  python-sympy is already the newest version.
  The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
   linux-headers-3.2.0-55-generic-pae gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 linux-headers-3.2.0-55       libubuntuoneui-3.0-1
   Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
  (basicpython)xxxxx@LinuxBox:~/pythonprojects/basicpython$
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, there are 2 issues here:

1. Yolk is not installed in your virtualenv. Since it is picking up yolk from the global modules you are getting a list of all global packages. For information about this problem check this question:
   [virtualenv yolk problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742980/virtualenv-yolk-problem)
2. Pandas module also doesnt seem to be installed in your virtualenv (I am guessing you used the default virtualenv creation which does not use any site packages). A quick way to check this is `pip freeze`. You should go ahead and install pandas in your virtualenv (`pip install pandas`) and then see if the same behavior occurs.

Comment: I tried reinstalling, however, the system thinks they are already there.

Comment: From your edit I see you tried installing the system packages. Can you try installing the python packages (pip install pandas)? Also, did pip freeze show up the modules you are looking for?