# Virtual environment build on Sublime Text 3 for Windows

Tags: python, windows, sublimetext3

I seem to be unable to run my Sublime Text 3 build with any virtual environment. My latest attempt has been to use the `Virtualenv` package in sublime text and use the following project settings:

```
{
 "folders":
 [
  {
   "path": "."
  }
 ],

    "virutalenv": "C:\\Users\\alexa\\Envs\\test5",
    "settings": "C:\\Users\\alexa\\Envs\\test5\\Scripts\\python" 
}
```

My desired `venv` has `pandas` installed:

```
C:\Users\alexa\Envs\test5\Scripts>activate
(test5) C:\Users\alexa\Envs\test5\Scripts>pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\alexa\envs\test5\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2 in c:\users\alexa\envs\test5\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.0 in c:\users\alexa\envs\test5\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\users\alexa\envs\test5\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\alexa\envs\test5\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas)

(test5) C:\Users\alexa\Envs\test5\Scripts>
```

But when I run my build, which is set to `Python + Virtualenv`, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\SBP\first.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\SBP\first.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\SBP]
[path: C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Python35-32;C:\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python35-32\Scripts\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

Comment: There isn't much indication that your build is running from the virtual environment you've made.

Comment: @pvg I agree; so how do I do this better?

Comment: where are you setting these 'python virtualenv' settings? One thing you can try as a test is launching sublime from your activated venv. But for it to work independently, sublime has to be aware of and activate your specific venv which seems to be what's missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this question? It seems pretty similar, and has some helpful responses. Also, try pip freeze within your virtual environment to see if pandas is installed in your virtual environment.

[Python modules not found in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20314734/8133368)

Comment: Yes, `pandas` shows up with `pip freeze`. I think the problem is how connecting to virtualenv

Comment: Have you tried to run the script manually in the python interpreter after running `workon` on your environment name?